# How to get slick slider to show in Shopify?

Tags: javascript, css, slider, shopify, slick.js

I'm trying to get my featured collections section on my Shopify site to display as a slider. It looks like it is already installed on the Debut theme but I can't get it to initialize. I'm not getting any errors in my console so does anyone know how to get the slick slider to display correctly?

Here is my site and password to view the site if it's helpful.

https://test-shop-986573.myshopify.com/

password: shecka

```
<ul data-slides="{{section.settings.grid}}" class="grid grid--uniform grid--view-items collection-slider ">
```

```
{
  .slick-track {
    display: flex;
  }
  .product-card {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .slick-prev {
    left: 0;
    z-index: 999;
  }
  .slick-next {
    right: 0;
    z-index: 999;
  }
  padding-right: 25px;
  
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.collection-slider').each(function(){
    var num_slides = 2;
    if(window.innerWidth >= 750)
    {
    var num_slides = $(this).data('slides');
    }
    $(this).slick({slidesToShow:num_slides});
    
  });
  
});
```

```
{% case section.settings.grid %}
  {% when 2 %}
    {%- assign max_height = 530 -%}
  {% when 3 %}
    {%- assign max_height = 345 -%}
  {% when 4 %}
    {%- assign max_height = 250 -%}
  {% when 5 %}
    {%- assign max_height = 195 -%}
{% endcase %}

{% if section.settings.layout == 'grid' %}
  {%- assign limit = section.settings.grid | times: section.settings.rows -%}
{% else %}
  {%- assign limit = 16 -%}
{% endif %}

{% paginate collection.products by limit %}

<div data-section-id="{{ section.id }}" data-section-type="collection-template">
  <header class="collection-header">
    {%- assign is_filter_by_available = false -%}
    {%- if section.settings.tags_enable and collection.all_tags.size > 0 -%}
      {%- assign is_filter_by_available = true -%}
    {%- endif -%}

    {% if section.settings.show_collection_image and collection.image %}
      <div class="collection-hero">
        <div class="collection-hero__image ratio-container lazyload js"
             data-bgset="{% include 'bgset', image: collection.image %}"
             data-sizes="auto"
             data-parent-fit="cover"
             style="background-image: url('{{ collection.image | img_url: '300x300' }});"></div>
        <noscript>
          <div class="collection-hero__image" style="background-image: url({{ collection.image | img_url: '2048x600', crop: 'top' }});"></div>
        </noscript>
        <div class="collection-hero__title-wrapper">
          <h1 class="collection-hero__title page-width">
              <span class="visually-hidden">{{ 'collections.general.collection_label' | t }}: </span>
              {{ collection.title }}
          </h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      {% if is_filter_by_available == false and section.settings.sort_enable == false %}
        <div class="page-width">
          <span class="filters-toolbar__product-count">{{ 'collections.general.items_with_count' | t: count: collection.products_count }}</span>
        </div>
      {% endif %}
      {% if collection.description != blank %}
        <div class="rte collection-description page-width">
          {{ collection.description }}
        </div>
      {% endif %}
    {% else %}
      <div class="page-width">
        <div class="section-header text-center">
          <h1>
              <span class="visually-hidden">{{ 'collections.general.collection_label' | t }}: </span>
              {{ collection.title }}
          </h1>
          {% if collection.description != blank %}
            <div class="rte">
              {{ collection.description }}
            </div>
          {% endif %}
          {% if is_filter_by_available == false and section.settings.sort_enable == false %}
            <span class="filters-toolbar__product-count">{{ 'collections.general.items_with_count' | t: count: collection.products_count }}</span>
          {% endif %}
        </div>
      </div>
    {% endif %}

    {% if is_filter_by_available or section.settings.sort_enable %}
      <div class="filters-toolbar-wrapper{% if is_filter_by_available %} filters-toolbar--has-filter{% endif %}">
        <div class="page-width">
          <div class="filters-toolbar">
            <div class="filters-toolbar__item-wrapper">
              {% if section.settings.tags_enable %}
                {% unless collection.all_tags.size == 0 %}
                  <div class="filters-toolbar__item-child">
                    <label class="filters-toolbar__label select-label" for="FilterTags">{{ 'collections.filters.title_tags' | t }}</label>
                    <div class="filters-toolbar__input-wrapper select-group">
                      <select class="filters-toolbar__input hidden" name="FilterTags" id="FilterTags" aria-describedby="a11y-refresh-page-message a11y-selection-message">
                        <option value="{{ collection.url }}">{{ 'collections.filters.all_tags' | t }}</option>
                        {% for tag in collection.all_tags %}
                          {%- assign new_url = tag | link_to_tag: tag | split: 'href="' | last | split: '"' | first -%}
                          <option value="{{ new_url }}"{% if current_tags contains tag %} selected="selected"{% endif %}>{{ tag }}</option>
                        {% endfor %}
                      </select>
                      {% include 'icon-chevron-down' %}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                {% endunless %}
              {% endif %}

              {% if section.settings.sort_enable %}
                <div class="filters-toolbar__item-child">
                  {%- assign sort_by = collection.sort_by | default: collection.default_sort_by -%}
                  <label class="filters-toolbar__label select-label" for="SortBy">{{ 'collections.sorting.title' | t }}</label>
                  <div class="filters-toolbar__input-wrapper select-group">
                    <select name="sort_by" id="SortBy"
                      class="filters-toolbar__input hidden"
                      aria-describedby="a11y-refresh-page-message a11y-selection-message"
                      data-default-sortby="{{ collection.default_sort_by }}"
                    >
                      {%- for option in collection.sort_options -%}
                        <option value="{{ option.value }}" {% if option.value == sort_by %}selected="selected"{% endif %}>{{ option.name }}</option>
                      {%- endfor -%}
                    </select>
                    {% include 'icon-chevron-down' %}
                  </div>
                </div>
              {% endif %}
            </div>

            <div class="filters-toolbar__item filters-toolbar__item--count">
              <span class="filters-toolbar__product-count">{{ 'collections.general.items_with_count' | t: count: collection.products_count }}</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    {% endif %}
  </header>

  <div class="page-width" id="Collection">
    {% if section.settings.layout == 'grid' %}
      {% case section.settings.grid %}
      {% when 2 %}
        {%- assign grid_item_width = 'medium-up--one-half' -%}
      {% when 3 %}
        {%- assign grid_item_width = 'small--one-half medium-up--one-third' -%}
      {% when 4 %}
        {%- assign grid_item_width = 'small--one-half medium-up--one-quarter' -%}
      {% when 5 %}
        {%- assign grid_item_width = 'small--one-half medium-up--one-fifth' -%}
      {% endcase %}

      <ul class="grid grid--uniform{% if collection.products_count > 0 %} grid--view-items{% endif %}">
        {% for product in collection.products %}
          <li class="grid__item grid__item--{{section.id}} {{ grid_item_width }}">
            {% include 'product-card-grid', max_height: max_height, product: product, show_vendor: section.settings.show_vendor %}
          </li>
        {% else %}
          {% comment %}
          Add default products to help with onboarding for collections/all only.

          The onboarding styles and products are only loaded if the
          store has no products.
          {% endcomment %}
          {% if collection.handle == 'all' and collection.all_vendors.size == 0 and collection.all_types.size == 0 %}
            <li class="grid__item">
              <div class="grid grid--uniform">
                {% for i in (1..limit) %}
                  <div class="grid__item {{ grid_item_width }}">
                    <div class="grid-view-item">
                      <a href="#" class="grid-view-item__link">
                        <div class="grid-view-item__image">
                          {% capture current %}{% cycle 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 %}{% endcapture %}
                          {{ 'product-' | append: current | placeholder_svg_tag: 'placeholder-svg' }}
                        </div>
                        <div class="h4 grid-view-item__title">{{ 'homepage.onboarding.product_title' | t }}</div>
                        <div class="grid-view-item__meta">
                          <span class="product-price__price">$19.99</span>
                        </div>
                      </a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                {% endfor %}
              </div>
            </li>
          {% else %}
            {%- assign is_empty_collection = true -%}
          {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
      </ul>
    {% else %}
      <ul class="list-view-items">
        {% for product in collection.products %}
          <li class="list-view-item">
            {% include 'product-card-list', product: product, show_vendor: section.settings.show_vendor %}
          </li>
        {% else %}

          {% comment %}
          Add default products to help with onboarding for collections/all only.

          The onboarding styles and products are only loaded if the
          store has no products.
          {% endcomment %}
          {% if collection.handle == 'all' and collection.all_vendors.size == 0 and collection.all_types.size == 0%}
            {% for i in (1..4) %}
              <li class="list-view-item">
                <a href="#" class="list-view-item__link">
                  <div class="list-view-item__image-column">
                    <div class="list-view-item__image-wrapper">
                      <div class="list-view-item__image">
                        {% capture current %}{% cycle 1, 2, 3, 4 %}{% endcapture %}
                        {{ 'product-' | append: current | placeholder_svg_tag: 'placeholder-svg' }}
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="list-view-item__title-column">
                    <div class="list-view-item__title">{{ 'homepage.onboarding.product_title' | t }}</div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="list-view-item__price-column">
                    <span class="product-price__price">$19.99</span>
                  </div>
                </a>
              </li>
            {% endfor %}
          {% else %}
            {%- assign is_empty_collection = true -%}
          {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
      </ul>
    {% endif %}

    {% if is_empty_collection %}
      <div class="grid__item small--text-center">
        <p class="text-center">{{ 'collections.general.no_matches' | t }}</p>
      </div>
    {% endif %}

    {%- if paginate.pages > 1 -%}
      {% include 'pagination', paginate: paginate %}
    {%- endif -%}
  </div>
</div>

{% endpaginate %}
```

Comment: Please show us the code for the collection.liquid, where you loop through and output the collection items. It looks like there aren't being outputted any items, and therefore there aren't anything to make a slider from, if that makes sense.

Comment: Hey @ralphwayTow I've added the code to my collection template. Thank you!